# MAUI & iPhone Release fails to codesign

Tags: ios, maui, codesign

I have an MAUI mobile app that is not compiling/codesigning on iOS and I'm looking for some help on identifying what to do.

I am using a 3rd party library, VideoLan.LibVLC (https://www.nuget.org/packages/VideoLAN.LibVLC.iOS) and I have pairing to the mac setup (Mac in the cloud via RDP). I was able to get my certificates setup, the package name is aligned.

> /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1:
> Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: XXX XXX (XXX)"
>
> iPhone/Release/com.xxx.ios.app/Frameworks/DynamicMobileVLCKit.framework: errSecInternalComponent
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(2163,3): error : Failed to codesign

After some googling it seems that this is typically caused by a keychain not being unlocked. I have double checked, all certificates are trusted & the keychain is unlocked. I've rebooted the machine to ensure they reload for some goofy reason.

The only thing I can think of is that this DynamicMobileVLCKit is some how causing codesign to fail, but the error doesn't seem to give enough details.